# Is it possible to update the textview while the user is not using the application?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, sharedpreferences

I have a project in where the Android application should receive and send sms. I just want to update the textview because the button visibility will depend on the textview.

Like, if the application receive sms with 'ON'. The on button will show. And the off button will hide. And otherwise.

I also used SharedPreferences to saved and resume the last state of the application whether it was being close or maybe the device is turned off.

The problem is that, I dont know how to make my application update and saved by SharedPreferences while it is not using by the user. Is it possible?

Please help for the best way to solved this problem. Thank you in advanced! :)

Comment: Well if you have a event where you want to save something, like a BroadcastReceiver to receive SMS you can save to preferences there, can you post what have you tried?

Comment: How to save to preferences the receive SMS while the appliction is not using? Please help.

Comment: Using SharedPreferences from the BroadcastReceiver where you get the sms

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Additional question sir, can I call a method from MainActivity.java to SMSReceiver.java to execute the code inside that method?

Comment: If you have a reference to it, of course you can.

Comment: Awhile ago, I try to call a toast() method from MainActivity.java to SMSReceiver.java(which is only running background includes BroadcastReceiver) to see if the method that I called will executed which I include toast.maketext() in the toast() method. And yes it executed because the toast message appear.

Comment: Now, I thought if I only put the code with the SharedPreferences that are executed when the application is using will put on that toast() method, it will also executed as what the toast() method run awhile ago and my problem will be solved. But then, I don't know how can I make that happen because I cannot call the method wherein the code is in there. Please help.